# Parity Ethereum service not working

Tags: parity

I downloaded the 2.2.7 stable binary for Ubuntu from the Parity website. I set it up as a service, using the standard files. I changed nothing. However when I did;

```
sudo systemctl start parity
```

It did not start and so I did;

```
sudo systemctl status parity
● parity.service - Parity Ethereum Daemon
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/parity.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: start-limit-hit) since Tue 2019-01-29 19:46:01 UTC; 3min 22s ago
  Process: 30492 ExecStart=/usr/bin/parity --config /etc/parity/config.toml (code=exited, status=203/EXEC)
 Main PID: 30492 (code=exited, status=203/EXEC)

Jan 29 19:46:01 ip-172-31-19-123 systemd[1]: parity.service: Service hold-off time over, scheduling restart.
Jan 29 19:46:01 ip-172-31-19-123 systemd[1]: Stopped Parity Ethereum Daemon.
Jan 29 19:46:01 ip-172-31-19-123 systemd[1]: parity.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
Jan 29 19:46:01 ip-172-31-19-123 systemd[1]: Failed to start Parity Ethereum Daemon.
Jan 29 19:46:01 ip-172-31-19-123 systemd[1]: parity.service: Unit entered failed state.
Jan 29 19:46:01 ip-172-31-19-123 systemd[1]: parity.service: Failed with result 'start-limit-hit'.
```

I thought perhaps it was already running, but that was not the case;

```
ubuntu@ip-172-31-19-123:~/Parity$ ps auxww | grep -i parity
ubuntu   30506  0.0  0.1  12944  1028 pts/0    S+   19:50   0:00 grep --color=auto -i parity
```

What does start-limit-hit mean?

I then ran it like this which worked fine. Probably I will just run it like this, and add the line to rc.local which is executed on startup - but I would like to know why the service did not work.

```
nohup ./parity --light >> parity.log &
```

Answer (score 1):

> Process: 30492 ExecStart=/usr/bin/parity --config
>   /etc/parity/config.toml (code=exited, status=203/EXEC)

I faced a similar issue and had to check `parity.service` in the git repo. [here](https://github.com/paritytech/parity-ethereum/blob/master/scripts/parity.service#L7)

The reason was Parity daemon was looking for `config.toml` file at non-existing path `/etc/parity/`.

Hope this helps.